# ¿Cómo llamar a una función sin que se muestre el resultado en el DOM en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Estoy insertando un video desde YouTube en mi sitio web, el objetivo es traer el Id del video guardando en una BD, el video en YouTube estará  oculto, esto quiero decir que solo se podrá visualizar el video por las personas que tengan esta URL del video, pero solo quiero que sea visible en mi sitio web.
Estoy buscando varias formas para solucionar este problema, es decir que no se muestre el ID del video, mas bien ocultarlo.
Una de mis ideas es realizar una función con la consulta en PHP do donde se traigan los datos del video y después llamar esta función, pero aun así muestra el resultado.
Este es un ejemplo:

```
<?php
function getid(){
    $IDvideo = 'iWfncDG3M90';
    echo  $IDvideo;
}

?>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php getid();?>" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Cabe aclarar que esto es un ejemplo sencillo, ya que estoy usando la Api de Youtube para mostrar el video. El objetivo es el mismo. Alguna idea en la cual pueda realizar esto. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Este es mi código usando la Api de YouTube. Mi idea es pasar el parámetro videoId como función que llame otra función con el resultado.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: '750',
    height: '355',
   videoId: function() { 
        
 },
    playerVars: {
    'controls' : 0,
    'modestbranding' : 1,
    'rel' : 0,
    'showinfo' : 0,
    'autoplay': 1,
    'mute' : 1
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Saludos. Si usas un tercero (en tu caso YouTube); las condiciones para mostrar o no el video las pone ese tercero. Si de alguna forma creas (dedicando tiempo) a que tu sitio desde el servidor reciba el video y de allí lo envíe a tu visitante ya pudieras realizarlo como deseas (ocultando el ID). Esto es una idea no necesariamente la (única) solución.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. En si,  seria mas que nada que YouTube no permitirá eso, ¿cierto?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Mientras llega alguien con conocimiento del tema; las veces que he usado **YT** siempre he puesto el **ID** ya que como lugar de origen, YT *necesita* saber que vídeo solicitas; y actualmente lo hace por el ID; bueno por todo lo que la URL se forma del mismo como cuando lo visitas directamente.

Comment: Que tal. Así lo estoy realizando, pero como podrás notar el ID se tiene que establecer directamente, lo que trataba de igual manera es convertir el parámetro ID en una función donde llame a una función de fuera que traiga los datos, esto con JS. Actualizo la pregunta para que notes como fue mi idea, esta idea no logro completarla.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta con el Código de la Api

Comment: Lo que deseas hacer no es posible con la política de visibilidad "oculto". En youtube puedes restringir que un vídeo no se vea en terceras páginas, pero no puedes especificar las que permites y las que no. Además, en cuanto muestres el vídeo en tu página un usuario cualquiera puede copiar y pegar esa URL en otra pestaña y ver el vídeo fuera de tu página, compartir el vídeo con terceros (o incluso publicarlo en redes sociales) y todo el mundo tendrá acceso a él. Podrías ofuscar el código HTML para ocultar la URL en el inspector de código, pero en el de tráfico saldrá la URL en claro.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, seria buscar alguna otra alternativa, como vimeo?

Comment: Tampoco. La única forma de conseguir lo que quieres alojar tú mismo los vídeos y controlar su visualización si el usuario ha iniciado sesión y tiene permisos para verlo. Eso sí, esto no impediría que el usuario pudiera descargarse el vídeo.

Comment: Si, así es es lo mas fácil establecerlos por mi mismo,  pero me preocupa que no soporte el servidor en que tantos usuarios puedan visualizar este video al mismo tiempo, por ese motivo quería utilizar YouTube.

Comment: Lo que más se acerca a lo que quieres hacer es el concepto de [vídeo privado de Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprivate-videos), pero me temo que es demasiado restrictivo. En cuanto a ocultar algo que es parte del cliente, **eso es imposible**, hablar de ofuscar el código cliente es simplemente una ilusión, cualquiera con conocimientos básicos podrá obtener el contenido explorando el código fuente.

Comment: Entiendo, el video privado en si, se necesitaría iniciar sesión para poder verlo y causaría conflicto ya que al parecer se necesitan los corres que verán este video, cierto?.

Comment: hasta el momento youtube no provee en su api; host para videos privados que no pasen por su sistema o métodos de pagos...

incluso los videos estara publicos en youtube... el otro problema que veo es que desean implemenatar un tipo de video privado pero no explicas el por que o el contexto de tu desarrollo. me parece que youtube no es el camino correcto.